# What does k -> * mean?

Tags: haskell

In the prelude, the type information about `ReaderT` says:

```
newtype ReaderT r (m :: k -> *) (a :: k)
  = ReaderT {runReaderT :: r -> m a}
```

What does `(m :: k -> *)` it mean? `m` takes an argument of type `k`, but `m` is a higher kinded type.

Information about higher kinded looks also wired:

```
Prelude> :k ReaderT
ReaderT :: * -> (k -> *) -> k -> *
```

Comment: `k` can be an arbitrary kind, it is not limited to the valid Haskell type `*`.

Comment: @ThreeFx  can I open a chat with you, because I am living in Zürich too.

Comment: Sure, do so, best include the link in the comments for further reference.

Comment: Can you please do it, I do not know how to.

Comment: It means that we can have nonsense like `ReaderT () Any Monad :: *`.  When `PolyKinds` came out, I imagine people attempted to generalize signatures that could. This is one of those. There are probably some contrived use cases. [Here](https://hub.darcs.net/ross/transformers/issue/5) is the relevant issue.

Answer (score 0):

The fragment `(m :: k -> *)` indicates that `m` is a type variable of *kind* `k -> *`.  This, in turn, means that `m` is a higher-kinded type that takes a type (of **unspecified** kind `k`) and produces a concrete type (i.e., a type of kind `*`).

All you're seeing here is GHC's attempt to infer the most general possible kind for a type (the same way it infers the most general possible type for a function).

Here's the reason this kind is inferred:  The actual *definition* of `ReaderT` given in module `Control.Monad.Trans.Reader` in the `transformers` package is:

```
newtype ReaderT r m a = ReaderT { runReaderT :: r -> m a }
```

The right-hand side implies that `r` and `m a` must both be concrete types (of kind `*`).  From this, it's possible to infer that `r` is of kind `*` and that `m` takes a single argument and produces a concrete type (so `m` is of kind `something -> *`).  Since there is no constraint placed on the kind of `a` by this definition, GHC decides that it can have arbitrary kind `k`, implying that the kind of `m` is `k -> *` for an arbitrary `k`.

This explains both:

```
> :i ReaderT
...
newtype ReaderT r (m :: k -> *) (a :: k)
  = ReaderT {runReaderT :: r -> m a}
...
```

and:

```
> :k ReaderT
ReaderT ::    * -> (k -> *) -> k -> *
-- kinds of:  r        m       a    `-- (ReaderT r m a)
```

Now, just because GHC infers such a general kind doesn't indicate that it has any use or purpose.  Since all monads are of kind `* -> *`, the only way to create a `ReaderT` that didn't use an `a` of kind `*` would be to use it to "transform" an `m` that wasn't actually a monad, and then you wouldn't be able to use any of the functions in `Control.Monad.Reader` that use a `Monad m` constraint (which is almost all of them).  So, in this case, the generalization is useless.